# the trait `std::default::Default` is not implemented for AccountId

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I have an issue. I wold like to store a struct using AccountId as key:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, PartialEq, Eq, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo)]
    pub struct Contract<Origin, AccountId, Amount> {
        pub origin: Origin,
        pub to: AccountId,
        pub amount: Amount,
        pub current_block_number: u64,
        pub work_days_in_block_number: u64,
        pub take_action_days_in_block: u64,
    }


    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn contract_sender)]
    pub(super) type ContractSender<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::AccountId, Contract<T::AccountId, T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>>, ValueQuery>;


    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn contract_receiver)]
    pub(super) type ContractReceiver<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::AccountId, Contract<T::AccountId, T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>>, ValueQuery>;
```

But having this issue:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Contract<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>: std::default::Default` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/escrow/src/lib.rs:47:12
   |
47 |     #[pallet::pallet]
   |               ^^^^^^ the trait `std::default::Default` is not implemented for `Contract<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>`
   |
   = help: the trait `StorageInfoTrait` is implemented for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<Prefix, Hasher, Key, Value, QueryKind, OnEmpty, MaxValues>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `frame_support::traits::Get<Contract<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>>` for `GetDefault`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `QueryKindTrait<Contract<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>, GetDefault>` for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `StorageInfoTrait` for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageContractSender<T>, frame_support::Blake2_128Concat, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, Contract<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>, frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Contract<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>: std::default::Default` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/escrow/src/lib.rs:66:12
   |
66 |     #[pallet::storage]
   |               ^^^^^^^ the trait `std::default::Default` is not implemented for `Contract<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>`
```

I do not understand what's wrong :/
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

> I wold like to store a struct using AccountId as key.

This is not the problem. It's totally fine.

The problem is the `Contract` struct.
Because the `StorageMap` value require `Default`.
It contains an `AccountId` and the `AccountId` doesn't implement `Default`.

You could change this map's query type to `OptionQuery`.

---

Check the original PR for more information.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10403

Comment: Wouldn't using `OptionQuery` instead of `ValueQuery` solve the problem without the need to change the value type?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to change the type to `OptionQuery`. That's right! Because I don't have a computer nearby when I answer this question. I forgot the detail. I just want to tell you that you should use the option type here.

Comment: OK, so I'd suggest to edit the answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as previously mentioned, the `ValueQuery` forces `Contract` to default to some kind of default `Contract` with default `AccountId`, which doesn't exist, and `OptionQuery` allows it to just be `None`. Broke my head the first time I saw this error! :)